# startActivity dosen't work inside custom control (RadioButton)

Tags: android, custom-controls, android-intent, jradiobutton

I have a custom RadioButton class, i have placed it on Activity1. I am using its event "onClick" to open another Activity2. Below is the code:

```
public class custom_radiobutton extends RadioButton{

    Paint myPaint = new Paint();
    private Context cont;

    public custom_radiobutton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        cont = context;
    }

    public custom_radiobutton(Context context, AttributeSet attrbs) {
        super(context, attrbs);
        cont = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        String myText = (String) getText();
        canvas.drawText(myText, 10, 10, myPaint);
        this.setOnClickListener(radio_listener);
    }   

      OnClickListener radio_listener = new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) 
      {

          try
          {
               Intent intent = new Intent("com.moftak.db.ImageActivity"); 
               // next line do nothing..
           getContext().startActivity(intent); 

               // next line also not works
               //cont.startActivity(intent); 
          }
          catch(Exception ex)
          {
              Log.d("Image", "Error: "+ex.toString());
          }
      } 
    };
}
```

**EDIT:**
The problem is that the line "getContext().startActivity(intent); " is throwing below error:

```
 android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.moftak.db.ImageActivity (has extras) }
```

Can somebody help, please?

Thanks for your valuable time & help.

Comment: Is it giving any error or what?

Comment: Look in your Logcat for that debug line, or remove the catch(Exception ex)

Comment: @Adil Soomro
I have updated the question, yes its throwing the mentioned error.

Comment: Is your Activity defined in Manifest.xml. Show us your Manifest.xml also.

Comment: @Adil Soomro
Activity2 was not defined in the Maifest.xml, i have already updated my question, please see the last lines of my question.

Comment: @YaqubAhmad: Now accept your answer as well to fully close the Question. (i.e mark your answer as accepted)

Comment: @AdilSoomro: Thanks for your kind suggestion, but i can't accept my own question until tomorrow.

Comment: @AdilSoomro: I will be thankful if you can spare sometime of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906496/cant-attach-onclick-event-to-android-custom-autocompletetextview-from-xml-layou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please accept my apologies, i found the issue (**VERY BIG MISTAKE, sorry for that**), **the Activity2 was not specified in the AndroidManifest.xml**

Answer (score 1):

Try with this `cont.startActivity(intent);`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried it but the same result, not works.

Comment: Maybe is your intent, try this:  Intent intent = new Intent(YourActualClass.this, ImageActivity.class); startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

Comment: When i used below:
Intent intent = new Intent(DatabasesActivity.this, ImageActivity.class); 

Error displays, saying "No enclosing instance of the type DatabasesActivity is accessible in scope"

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(this, ImageActivity.class);

Comment: Actually @fr4n want to say:`Intent intent = new Intent(cont, ImageActivity.class);` and then `cont.startActivity(intent);`

Comment: same result, not works
both the getContext() & cont value is 'com.moftak.db.ImageActivity' which is the Actvity1, means correct value.

Answer (score 1):

that's because your `getContext()` method is returning the Context of your RadioButton, not the context of your activity (from the radiobutton's constructor). try `cont.startActivity(..`

also, when using the constructor for your RadioButton, try passing the instance of the activity itself (inside the activity, use `this` instead of `getApplicationContext()`).

Comment: Thanks @Josephus Villarey
I have already used the cont.startActivity(intent); & it not works.
I have checked & both the getContext() & cont value is 'com.moftak.db.ImageActivity' which is the Actvity1.

Comment: can you check if you're actually passing through the onClick method you've overridden?

Comment: Its throwing an error i have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(custom_radiobutton.this ImageActivity.class); 
               // next line do nothing..
           getContext().startActivity(intent);
```